# How to create a raster dataset from a known decimal extent?

Tags: arcobjects, raster, c#

I have an input raster pInputRaster. I want to create a new raster dataset called pOutputRasterDS that is the same width, height and cellsize as my input raster dataset (I'm not worried about populating the new raster with values at this moment in time). The input raster dataset has square cells.

I can get the input raster dataset information like so:

```
Type factoryTypefinalraster = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(
                            "esriDataSourcesRaster.RasterWorkspaceFactory");
IWorkspaceFactory pWSF = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance //DECLARE RASTER WORKSPACE FACTORY. THIS IS A SINGLETON OBJECT. ONLY ONE OF THESE PER PROGRAM
                            (factoryTypefinalraster);

ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IRasterDataset2 pInputRasterDS = (IRasterDataset2)pInputRaster

ISpatialReference sr = new PointClass();
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IEnvelope pREnv = pInputRaster.Extent;
double dLowerLeftX = pREnv.LowerLeft.X;
double dLowerLeftY = pREnv.LowerLeft.Y;
origin.PutCoords(dLowerLeftX, dLowerLeftY);
int NumBand = 1;

ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IRasterWorkspace2 pTempRWS2 = (IRasterWorkspace2)pWSF.OpenFromFile(strOutRasPath, 0);
string outfilename = "outputRas";
```

Now I have all that I need to call [IRasterWorkspace2.CreateRasterDataset()](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeoDatabase/IRasterWorkspace2_CreateRasterDataset.htm). Here I call that method:

```
IRasterDataset2 pOutputRasterDS = (IRasterDataset2)pTempRWS2.CreateRasterDataset(outfilename, "GRID", origin, pREnv.Width, pREnv.Height, cellsize, cellsize, NumBand, rstPixelType.PT_UCHAR, sr, true);
```

The issue arises in the implementation of this method. The method takes type int or type long as inputs for the width and the height. In my case, I am most often working with a geographic coordinate system with decimal degrees, so my width and height are of type double. Obviously, converting these values to int is not possible. Projecting the data beforehand is also not a possibility. Any alternate ideas? I have considered just making a copy of my current raster dataset and clearing all values of it, but have not explored this option further.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, row and column counts are integers, cell sizes are doubles.

Comment: Often your fallback method is superior, because it frequently is the case that you would like new rasters to have the same patterns of NoData cells as the old ones (they mask off areas you're not interested in). There are myriad ways to accomplish this, but one of the fastest and most direct is just to multiply all values in your current raster by zero. "Environmental" variables can influence the outcome, so you want to stipulate beforehand that any calculation done on a given raster will produce a raster of the same origin, cellsize, and dimensions and you do not want to have a "mask" raster.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. @mkennedy This is correct. I had not done this at the time because I did not know the pixel width and height of the raster was stored in an interface (IRasterProps is one way you can get at it). I at the time was using the formula (raster width/cellsize or raster height/cellsize) to get row and column sizes in pixels, which was of course not returning a whole number due to size limitations of double fields and automatic rounding. I ended up solving this by simply using my fallback method as whuber elaborated upon. I'll throw up a simple answer for this q.